# Generate flood map using qgis

Tags: qgis, tools, mapping, flood, depth

How can I generate a flood inundation map and flood depth using QGIS within 3 hours?

Comment: what did you tried so far and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Why three hours? GIS SE is not a place to do your work for you. Please read about what [topics you can ask here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: "within 3 hours" - lol

Comment: i'm here in 2023, i have the same problem and the same time constraint. and its because there's an actual flood, with actual people, so the map will help them.

Answer (score 5):

This is a good video that provides you with a walkthrough on generating a flood inundation map, [QGIS Flood Risk Mapping Walkthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PHWA_8doRyo). Also, you can find additional case study [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjkxdifk4bUAhUn44MKHdmCDJ0QFgg7MAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mdpi.com%2F2073-4441%2F6%2F5%2F1280%2Fpdf&usg=AFQjCNEU_UpKQ7vTSi9Yy5dbIsv1aUW2VA&sig2=AXkcaQNZa6yTFtOwR8Qr6g)